# how to pass id of the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec-rails

How to pass id. my controller is:

```
class AttachementsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @pdf = Attachement.find(params[:resume_id])
    # send_file(@pdf.file.url, :type => 'application/pdf', :disposition => 'inline',:stream => false)
    redirect_to @pdf.file.url
  end
end
```

and my test case of the controller is:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe AttachementsController do

  describe "GET 'index'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'index', :id => "@attachements.id"
      response.should be_success
    end
  end

end
```

and my error is:

```
 AttachementsController GET 'index' should be successful
     Failure/Error: get 'index', :id => "@attachements.id"
     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find Attachement without an ID
     # ./app/controllers/attachements_controller.rb:3:in `index'
     # ./spec/controllers/attachements_controller_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the quotes around @attachements.id.

```
get 'index', :id => @attachements.id
```

Comment: He also might need :resume_id instead of :id